# Order confirmations with asynchronous 3DS payments and webhooks

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Our application has different plans (Basic, Advanced, Pro). We use [Stripe](https://stripe.com/en-cy).

- Each Plan gives you X amount of credits per month.
- We credit each
  Customer with the credits when he has made a successful payment
  either by subscription creation, subscription update, or subscription
  cycle.
- The Customer is only credited on successful payment; we listen for the `invoice.payment_succeeded` webhook on our server and credit the user in our database.

The problem we face is this:

1. Customer attempts to use some credits. We detect that he has no
   credits nor a Plan.
2. Customer is prompted to sign up for plan.
3. Customer provides payment details.
4. Customer authorises 3DS on the client via `stripe.confirmCardPayment()`. He's informed that payment went through.
5. Customer attempts to use his credits. At this point the webhook `invoice.payment_succeeded`
   event did not arrive on our server to update our internal Customer and credit him his
   credits (or mark his subscription as `active`). So the user is still blocked from using our application. He's notified that he
   doesn't have any credits.
6. We eventually receive the webhook that payment has gone through and we update the
   customer subscription and credit his credits.

As you can see step 5 is problematic. The customer has paid however when he tries to use his credits he is informed he doesn't have any because the webhook that will credit his credits has not arrived yet on our server.

The webhook will arrive within the next minute or so but in the meantime the Customer is baffled that he paid for credits yet when trying to use them he's informed he doesn't have any.

How would you handle this?

### Possible solutions

#### Client sends HTTP call to credit his account

When `stripe.confirmCardPayment()` succeeds, send an HTTP call from client -> server to credit the user.

This solution is both insecure and error prone.

- It shifts the responsibility of crediting the user account to the client. Nothing would stop the client from sending forged HTTP calls to credit his own account.
- If the user closes down his browser immediately after `stripe.confirmCardPayment()` succeeds, the call to credit his account would never reach our servers.

#### Client polls server to query successful completion

Every `invoice.payment_succeeded` event gets processed on our server and saved in a table `successful_invoices`.

When `stripe.confirmCardPayment()` succeeds we poll our server to find out
if a successful invoice with the `invoice_id` exists in that table.

If it does, we hide the loading screen and tell the client that his payment was processed and his credits have been credited successfully.

This is our preferred solution for the time being.

Comment: You should make sure you create a Customer object in Stripe, and use that Customer with the initial payment. Then you can [retrieve the Customer's Invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list#list_invoices-customer) and check them immediately instead of waiting a few seconds for the webhook.

Comment: @taintedzodiac The problem is that it's the webhooks that credit the user in my database. For security and robustness reasons I can't have a client credit himself by sending requests after `stripe.confirmCardPayment()` succeeds.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I came across this question also working with Stripe, hoping to see an answer other than polling.

Comment: @sawprogramming unfortunately, polling...

Answer (score 2):

This is something we have faced already in various payment gateway integrations. You have to wait for the webhook to confirm the payment.

Then there needs to be a backup event that requests the gateway to confirm if the payment status is successful and so you can update the same in your records.

Normally, the webhooks do the needful else your payment_create event from your app can request that provider to check the status. But there is a mild chance of this not getting update unless you put a delay to check this post payment_create.

We tried adding a CRON that checks the status of the payment made in last 1 min. All payment having pending status from last run are picked status is updated from gateway provider. BUt in this case you need to be sure that no record should have a duplicate run in form of event from payment create and added to cron as well at same time.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that when the user creates a new subscription I want to show a loading screen that only turns off when the payment went through and his account properly credited. I'm not facing any problem with the webhooks themselves. I may have such problems, but that's not the point of my question.

Comment: You may be managing the state for transactions. You can add a middleware to every api request that may check the status if there is any pending payment (not the expired or failed subscription) and throw CustomException till the payment is not completed. Frontend you can handle it at two points, one on the same page, making request to check if the payment is succesful. This request needs to be made after short durations  and if success found , user can be redirected .

Comment: Thanks, that's polling which is something I've thought about and for the time being seems like a nice choice. I'm wondering whether there's a commonly used "standard" technique to solve this that doesn't involve polling.